# reg ex newby - how do you specify to match a characters but not include it in the output?

Tags: regex

Really simple situation:

Eg. in this string:

`my dog said "woof" today`

I would like to get the string in quotes, but without the quotes...

--- more detail ---

Unfortunately the regex is via 3rd party software so I don't know the underlying engine.

Here's the string:

```
href="http://pagingdrgupta.blogs.cnn.com/2010/08/17/dengue-fever-increases-in-florida/?hpt=T2">Dengue outbreak
```

Current regex:

`(https?://)?([-\w]+(\.\w[-\w]*)+|([a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?\.))+(com|edu|biz|gov|in(t|fo)|mil|net|org|[a-z][a-z]\.[a-z][a-z])\S*)`

this returns:

`http:.../?hpt=T2">Dengue`

Adding `"` to start and end of regex works, but includes the `"`.

Perhaps there's another way?

Comment: Your question only says you want to match quoted strings without the quotes, but your regex is obviously intended to match a URL--what gives?  Are you trying to match all URLs, or URLs that are in quotes, or what?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to depend on the "flavour" of regex that you are using. If your regex engine supports [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (positive lookbehind, positive lookahead, negative lookbehind, and negative lookahead), you can do this.

The syntax also varies by flavour, so if you edit your question and/or tags to show what language you're working in, you can get a more specific answer.

Comment: Unforunately the regex is via 3rd party software so I don't know the underlying engine. |

Here's the string:

href="http://pagingdrgupta.blogs.cnn.com/2010/08/17/dengue-fever-increases-in-florida/?hpt=T2">Dengue outbreak
|
Current regex:

(https?://)?([-\w]+(\.\w[-\w]*)+|([a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?\.))+(com|edu|biz|gov|in(t|fo)|mil|net|org|[a-z][a-z]\.[a-z][a-z])\S*)
|
this returns:

http:.../?hpt=T2">Dengue
|
Adding " to start and end of regex works, but includes the ".  | Perhaps there's another way?

Comment: @Kieryn add that to your question

Comment: Does your regex software not support capture groups?  If you're string only has one href in it perhaps something like `href="([^"]+)"` would work (the url should be captured).